# Execute Multiple SQL Server Queries for 2 Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 Linked Servers "NewDump" and "OldDump" (Dumps from different dates). I have queries to compare tables from these dumps (like FTM$, FSF$ etc). Each query compares a table between these linked server. Is there a way i can run all these ".SQL" queries (FTM.SQL and FSF.SQL) using a batch file together for automation

eg queries: FTM.SQL

```
FROM (
SELECT  *
FROM NewDump...FTM$) t1

FULL OUTER JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM OldDump...FTM$) t2

ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE

t1.id IS NULL OR
t2.id IS NULL
```

eg FSF.SQL Query

```
FROM (
SELECT  *
FROM NewDump...FSF$) t1

FULL OUTER JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM OldDump...FSF$) t2

ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE

t1.id IS NULL OR
t2.id IS NULL
```

The Queries FSF.SQL and FTM.SQL are stored in C:\Users\user\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Agent to schedule any SQL Statements. It would be neater if you created stored procedures out of the aforementioned queries and scheduled those.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me to run multiple .SQL files.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
PRINT 'Start...'
:On Error exit

   :r C:\Queries\FTM.sql
   :r C:\Queries\FSF.sql


PRINT 'Finish...'
GO
```

Comment: Can any one please help me output result in .xls for  FTM.sql and FSF.sql seperately once the query is implemented